# if else statement not working exactly

Tags: php, if-statement

I have written a code with else if statements but its not working exactly as i want.

Code:

```
<?php
if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y")
{
    echo "Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M")
{
    echo "Monthly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Monthly";
}
else
{
    echo "Free";
}
  ?>
```

Its only echo 1,2,5 statement but not 3,4 .If i removes 1 and 2nd statement then it works perfectly.

Comment: What does `$ids_fetch` do?

Comment: You'll need to provide more info: what does `$ids_fetch` contain, exactly?

Comment: i am fetching s_type and register from database and comparing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and second statment will alwys be true if `Y` or `M` will be present and script won't go further to inspect later statments, so if you want to use two variables in your statment you need to use in both conditions

```
if(($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y") && ($ids_fetch["register"] != "R"))
```

same for the second one wich should be

```
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M")  && ($ids_fetch["register"] !="R"))
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it :) Alternatively, the OP could just put the most specific match first then the less specific one

Comment: @user2345654 you welcome, don't forget to accept answer for help people in the future with similar problems

Answer (score 1):

In this bit of code 3 and 4 will never be true. if `$ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y"` is true, then it will never even evaluate if 3 is true.

The same is happening with 2 and 4. You can fix it by reordering it:

```
<?php
if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Monthly";
} 
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y")
{
    echo "Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M")
{
    echo "Monthly";
}
else
{
    echo "Free";
}
?>
```

or probably preferably use a switch statement

```
<?php
switch($ids_fetch['s_type'])
{
    case 'Y':
    if($ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
    {
        echo "Ref-Yearly";
    } else {
        echo "Yearly";
    }
    break;

    case 'M':
    if($ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
    {
        echo "Ref-Monthly";
    } else {
        echo "Monthly";
    }
    break;

    default:
    echo "free";
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the 3rd and 4th conditions will never execute.

With an If/Else If/Else statement, only one of them will execute. This is because once one condition is reached, that block will be executed, and the rest will not be evaluated. If no conditions are true, then the else will block will be executed.

Your 1st Condition `($ids_fetch["s_type"] == "Y")` and your 3rd condition `($ids_fetch["s_type"] == "Y" && $ids_fetch["register"] == "R")` are close, but not the same. If the 3rd condition is to be met, then the 1st condition will necessarily need to be true. Thusly, it will be evaluated, and executed, and the 3rd will be skipped.

The same goes for your 2nd condition and your 4th.

I would suggest putting the 3rd and 4th as the 1st and 2nd, and your logic should work.

```
<?php
if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M" && $ids_fetch["register"]=="R")
{
    echo "Ref-Monthly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="Y")
{
    echo "Yearly";
}
else if($ids_fetch["s_type"]=="M")
{
    echo "Monthly";
}

else
{
    echo "Free";
}
  ?>
```